# Constant string with interpolation

Tags: swift

I have a string with interpolation like this

```
let userID = 123
let userProfileUrl = "website.com/user/\(userID)"
```

I would like make `website.com/user/\(userID)` a constant but still remain its interpolation, so that I can interpolate it with an `userID`.

I wonder if anyone knows a good way to do that

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "*I would like make `website.com/user/\(userID)` a constant but still remain its interpolation*"? Do you mean that want to be able to interpolate in arbitrary `userID`s without having to repeat the string literal `"website.com/user/\(userID)"` each time?

Answer (score 1):

You can make userProfileUrl a lazy var. In this case you would need to specify the type of the userProfileUrl (i.e. `String`) and would need to use `self.userID` instead of userID

```
let userID = 123
lazy var userProfileUrl: String = "website.com/user/\(self.userID)"
```

Or if both properties are constants, and don't depend on an instance of the class you can place them outside of the class definition and it should work:

```
let userID = 123
let userProfileUrl = "website.com/user/\(userID)"

class MyClass {

}
```

You can also make `userProfileUrl` a computed property

```
let userID = 123

var userProfileUrl: String {
    return "website.com/user/\(userID)"
}
```

If you don't like the extra lines that the computed property adds you could format it so that it's all on one line

```
let userID = 123
var userProfileUrl: String { return "website.com/user/\(userID)" }
```

Comment: The computed property is the correct answer. Lazy property is not.

Comment: What's the point of a computed property if `userID` is a `let` constant?

Comment: This is the exact type of case Computed Properties are meant to solve, and they do them much better than anything else. IMO

Comment: @Hamish, OP was wanting to make userID dynamic.

Answer (score 0):

```
var userProfileURL: (String) -> String = {
    return "website.com/user/\($0)"
}

userProfileURL(userID)
```

This works but I would consider using an enum. You can now create a new case per endpoint.

```
enum Website {

    case UserProfile(Int)

    var base: String { return "http://website.com" }
    var path: String {
        switch self {
        case let .UserProfile(userID):
            return "user/\(userID)"
        }
    }
    var url: URL { return URL(string: "\(base)/\(path)")! }
}

let userProfileUrl = Website.UserProfile(123).url
```

Answer (score -2):

This might be a place where you want to use `NSString`'s bridging to `String` and it's [`-initWithFormat`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/foundation/nsstring/1497402-initwithformat):

```
let userProfileUrl = String(format: "website.com/user/%d", userId)
```

Comment: @LeoNatan My reading of the question was that the author is looking for a way to combine a dynamic user id with a static template string. If you believe that was not the question being asked then please help clarify the question and the problem to be solved.

Comment: `String(format:)` and the way the author generates their string is analogous, and was not what was asked. The question is, how to have a property which is "constant", but can be "manipulated" using a changing var. That is what a computed property provides.